# Starship HP increase on tier level up

Tags: vehicles, starfinder

When a ship is upgrade from tier 3 to tier 4 in starfinder it says there is a `hp increase`.  You can see this in the starfinder core rulebook, page 294, table 9-1.  It is also on table 9-1 here https://www.starjammersrd.com/equipment/starships/.

I don't see any notes on how much HP it gets in the book or online.  Does anyone have a pointer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information you are looking for is in the Base Frame stat block in parenthesis after the HP entry. You can read about it [here](https://www.starjammersrd.com/equipment/starships/#Understanding_Starships):

> Hull Points (HP): This is the total amount of damage a starships can take before it becomes inoperative. A starships with 0 Hull Points isn’t destroyed, though many of its systems are no longer functioning and it is no longer a threat to its enemies. **In a base frame stat block, the Hull Points entry also lists the HP increment, which is the number of Hull Points a starships with that frame automatically gains when its tier increases to 4 (and every 4 tiers thereafter).**